# YQL nesting statement

Tags: jquery, html, yql

Is it possible to create a YQL statement based off of the result of a YQL statement?

I have a YQL statement that provides me with a link. I really want to use that link to obtain data from the site. So I would like to have something similar to Excel Nesting If statements so that 1 YQL statement would provide the data that normally requires 2.

Example:

select response.results.result.links.homedetails from zillow.search where address = "1835 73rd Ave NE" and citystatezip = "98039" and zwsid = "X1-ZWz1cse68iatcb_13bwv"

Provides me with the link http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1835-73rd-Ave-NE-Medina-WA-98039/49118839_zpid/

And using that link I can build:

select ul.li from html where url="http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1835-73rd-Ave-NE-98039/1067902_zpid/" and xpath = '//div[@class="prop-mod prop-facts"]'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the results of a sub-select in the `in` clause.

```
SELECT ul.li
FROM html
WHERE xpath = '//div[@class="prop-mod prop-facts"]'
AND url IN (
    SELECT response.results.result.links.homedetails
    FROM zillow.search
    WHERE address = "1835 73rd Ave NE"
    AND citystatezip = "98039"
    AND zwsid = "X1-ZWz1cse68iatcb_13bwv"
)
```

<kbd>[Open this query in the YQL console](http://bit.ly/1jpwleR)</kbd>